# Project Dependency Error in Eclipse 3.8 Web development with EJB 3.0 in WebLogic 12

Tags: eclipse, weblogic, ejb-3.0

In Eclipse i have created an EAR Project with EJB Project, EJBClient Project and a WebProject.

I create a EntityBean Person and a SessionBean PersonTask at EJB Project. The Eclipse creates automatic a PersonTaskRemote Interface at EJBClient Project. And a Servlet wird created at the WebProject.

```
// at EJB Project
@Entity
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    ...setter and getter
}

//SessionBean
public class PersonTask implements PersonTaskRemote {
  Person findPerson(int personId){
      do something;
}
```

And

```
//In EJBClient Project
//The Interface
@Remote
public interface PersonTaskRemote {
   Person findPerson(int personId);
}
```

By Running, Eclipse get an Error! Because it hat a cycle in the Dependency (Project EJB and Project EJBClient). How can i do?

I had search in google, but in all funded tutorials the Interface in Client hat not the EntityBeans. only something like `String sayHello();` functions.

How can i avoid the Problem? Maybe create the local Entities in Client Project for the Interface?

Or get me some tutorials for those cases.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Move `Person` to the *EJBClient* module. It is clearly part of the client, because it is return value of business method. After that there is no cycle anymore, because *EJBClient* do not depend about other modules.

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer. can you explain why need a client project AND a web project? The Web ist a Client too?

Comment: It is not strictly needed. It is good idea though, because otherwise you will have dependency from EJB project to web project.